# InStr() returning position of where a char in string2 is in string1

Tags: excel, vba

I just started working a little in VBA and so maybe its something stupid I'm missing but it would be great if you could help me spot it. The problem is that I'm trying to count how many times a product type occurs. Due to the nature of using different sources, the type doesn't always have the exact same format. In my case I'm interested in all all types that contain the substring "etf". When I call the InStr() it always returns 1, aka the start position, so the function is considering the string "etf" to be nothing or of zero length (according to [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx)). I don't understand though why. Any help would be much appreciated.

The InStr() call is as follows `InStr(1, LCase(Sheets(ws).Cells(i, columnOfInterest).Value), "etf", 0)` where `ws` is the worksheet name, `i` is the row indicator (from a for loop), and `columnOfInterest` is the column that contains the product type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update, figured it out. I was working on my mac for once, and for some reason it was putting in a different style quotation marks than vba was expecting. Thus it was seeing "etf" as nothing or of zero length. Thank you all for the quick responses.

For anyone else reading this at a later stage, and you are having similar issues, check the if the quotation marks look like this: `"`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
InStr(LCase(Sheets(ws).Cells(i, columnOfInterest).Value), "etf")
```

Set your breaking point to this line and make sure `Sheets(ws).Cells(i, columnOfInterest).Value` returns a `string`.

Comment: I just checked and `Sheets(ws).Cells(i, columnOfInterest).Value` returns a string.  Also `ValType(Sheets(ws).Cells(i, columnOfInterest).Value)` returns `8` aka `String`

Comment: Okay so with this line of code you still get a "1" regardless?

Comment: Yeah the return of the `InStr()` is still `1`. None of the chars in "etf" matches the first char in `Sheets(ws).Cells(i, columnOfInterest).Value` so I'm assuming its return is based on the string "etf" being nothing or of zero length. I just don't understand how "etf" doesn't seem to qualify as a string

Comment: Try placing "etf" in a string variable. Can you post the string returned by the Sheets(ws).Cells(i, columnOfInterest).Value as well?

Comment: The String returned from `Sheets(ws).Cells(i, columnOfInterest).Value` is "GILT", I will try placing "etf" in a string variable, I'll let you know in a sec

Answer (score -1):

What are you actually trying?
If you want to find the number of instances then try these lines

```
 Val= Sheets(ws).Cells(i, columnOfInterest).Value
 Instances = Ubound(split(val , "etf")) - 1
```

If you are trying to find the position of the sub string then instr( ) should work fine

Comment: I'm using it to evaluate an If statement. So as follows `If InStr(LCase(Sheets(ws).Cells(i, columnOfInterest).Value), "etf") > 0 Then` The issue right now is that since the return is always 1, it takes all product types in to account, in stead of just the ones containing "etf"

Comment: Instr writes the position of first instance of the sub string so if "etf" occurs multiple time try using different logic

Comment: Thanks for the info. In my case I don't mind if it has multiple instances, just if its somewhere. My issue was that "etf" was being considered a string of zero length or nothing. I managed to solve the issue since my mac was putting in a different style quotation marks than the vba editor wanted for a string. E.G. they weren't the same as `"`